# How do I resize an image size automatically loaded in different browsers and screen size?

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph floated in right and an image floated in left. They are staying in the same row.
Now I want to make the paragraph and image height always be the equal, whichever browser they run in or whatever the window or screen size they get. Their size should match automatically. How do I do it?

In my program I have used `width` and `height`, but I am not sure they can fix the size automatically.

This piece of code I am working in: Also look in https://jsfiddle.net/d6pyyub2/

.HTML:

```
<p>
    The height of this paragraph must be the same as the height of
    the picture.
    The height of this paragraph must be the same as the height of
    the picture.
    The height of this paragraph must be the same as the height of
    the picture.

</p>
<div id="image">
    <img alt="" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Flower_jtca001.jpg" width="200" height="200" >
</div>
```

.CSS:

```
p{
    margin-left:240px;
}

#image{
    margin-top:-210px;
}
```

Comment: If you set the image `width` and `height` using pixels the image will always render at the same size in every browser

Comment: If you want to detect which browser the client is using you can use Javascript to do that:
if($.browser.chrome) {
   alert(1);
} else if ($.browser.mozilla) {
   alert(2);
} else if ($.browser.msie) {
   alert(3);
}

Comment: `-210px` this is a wrong way to position elements, look into floats, and CSS positioning

Comment: Mr. Alien, please tell me the right way, in my case.

Comment: There you go: https://jsfiddle.net/d6pyyub2/4/

Comment: @odedta that is worthy of an answer ...no?

Comment: Noel Walters, true, my post was confusing. I actually wanted to mean their Height should be same. I have edited the post

Comment: Look into flexbox, you'll be able to achieve what you want using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding a container you can set a block size dependent of another block size.
You set the image fixed to border of the container

```
#image{
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
}

#image img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

#container
{
    position: relative;
}
```

The `p` block set the height of the `#container`, and the image block follow the move. Fixed size by attributes in img tag are removed to set it at the full height of #image block.

https://jsfiddle.net/d6pyyub2/6/

**edit:**

As Daniel Ruf says in comment, there is a ratio problem with the image. Another solution is to set the image to the background of #image container.

https://jsfiddle.net/d6pyyub2/7/
In order to keep the ratio, the image will stop scale up his size if its witdh need to be superior to 240px, the fixed width of the first col.

Comment: a solution with flexbox is needed (RWD)

Comment: personally, I would scale this with JavaScript. You can easily retrieve the height of the block with the text and calculate the right width for the image (improves the behaviour of revision 6 of the jsfiddle solution)

Comment: I agree with you, js is a simple solution. question's flags don't mention js  maybe the restrict is to use only html and css.

Answer (score 0):

There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/d6pyyub2/4 this should solve your problem

```
.image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.para {
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: justify;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: odedta, thanks for answer. I think it solves the problem. But  I am afraid if I have misunderstood you. I actually wanted their height must be matched automatically. I have edited my post. however I hope you could figure it out what I wanted,right?

Comment: No, you want the text to always fit the image size?

Comment: I want them both be fitted always. For example if user squeeze the window, the text normally gets squeezed and height gets increased. in that situation the image's height also should increase so that their height matches and stay equal.

Comment: That makes no sense. When you keep the ratio of the dimensions of the image and the available space is less, the height will decrease and not increase or the ratio will be totally wrong.

Comment: Use @Marcassin solution, it is what you are looking for.